# (index):44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined ;at getanswer ((index):44) ;at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):204)

Tags: javascript, html

Here even though type is a valid type, i.e i have given type as radio which is valid type. And it is throwing an undefined error. But it is perfectly performing the operation, only in the console it is showing this error.
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined ;at getanswer ((index):44) ;at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):204) getanswer @ (index):44 onclick @ (index):204**

```
document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML = "";
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(i = 0; i<= e.length ; i++)
        {
            if(e[i].type == "radio")
            {
                if(e[i].checked)
                {
                    document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML += "Q" + e[i].name + "Answer you selected is :" + e[i].value+ "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
```

The html code

```
{% for Result in QUIZFORM %}
            <table>
 <br>
 <tr>
 <td>{{Result.id}} ) {{Result.questions}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice1}}">{{Result.choice1}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice2}}">{{Result.choice2}}</td>
   </tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice4}}">{{Result.choice4}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
<td><label id="correctanswer" class="ans" value="{{Result.correctanswer}}" style="display: none; color:green;">{{Result.correctanswer}}</label></td>
</tr>
      </table>
         {% endfor %}
            <hr/>
             <button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="getanswer();"> submitanswer </button><br>
```

What is causing this error? I know it is undefined type error, but even though type radio is defined in the html. It is displaying this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of the loop. In the loop, you try to get values that are both "less than and equals" to the number of elements. When you loop that, it gives an undefined element which leads to that error. Check the below code :

```js
document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML = "";
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  if (e[i].type == "radio") {
    if (e[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML += "Q" + e[i].name + "Answer you selected is :" + e[i].value + "<br/>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <br>
  <tr>
    <td>{{Result.id}} ) {{Result.questions}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <input type="text" id="useranswer"/>
    <td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice1}}">{{Result.choice1}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice2}}">{{Result.choice2}}</td>
  </tr>
  <td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice4}}">{{Result.choice4}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label id="correctanswer" class="ans" value="{{Result.correctanswer}}" style="display: none; color:green;">{{Result.correctanswer}}</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
<hr/>
<button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="getanswer();"> submitanswer </button><br>
```